# Returning min value as pointer from function

Tags: c++

Okay, so here's the deal. I have been working on this problem for a few days now and have tried every resource available to me. Just this morning I sent my last resort email to my Professor, but I want to keep trying to work on it while I wait for his answer. I am supposed to be returning a pointer to the smallest value in an array of random numbers between 0 - 1410 after assigning them through pointer arithmetic(got this part to work just fine). There was a skeleton file included for the assignment, but I like to build things from the ground up(using his parameters of course). Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int* find_smallest_number(int*, int);

int main()

{
    const int size = 10;
    int random_array[size] = {};

    int* smallestNumber = find_smallest_number(random_array, size);

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *(random_array + i) = rand()%1410;
        cout << random_array[i] << endl;
        cout << &*(random_array + i) << endl;
    }

    cout << "The smallest number is " << *smallestNumber << endl;

    return 0;
}


int* find_smallest_number(int *random_array, int size)

{

/*    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)

    {
       if(*(random_array + i) > *(random_array + 1))
       {
           return *(random_array + i);
       }
       else if(*(random_array + i) < *(random_array + 1))
       {
           return *(random_array+1);
       }

    } */

    return &min_element;
}
```

I honestly can not tell you how many different ways I've tried. This is just the most recent attempt(all have ended in massive amts of [headdesk]). Any tips or hints you guys can come up with for me to try?? I have tried creating another variable to hold the value/address, I have tried as many different ways of comparison as I currently know(this min_element thing was something I found on the internet). I can occasionally get my code to compile, but when I do it will only return the value/address of the FIRST element in the array(no matter what my code looks like). And if I try to return a pointer it gets angry and tells me "invalid conversion from int to int*" Please help me? (Also, sorry if the format of my code is off a little bit, I tried to follow the instructions for it but may have failed in that too :/)

Comment: So, what problems, exactly are you having? Show erroneous output or error messages.

Comment: You seem to be calling `find_smallest_number` **before** you've filled the array with values.  That's not going to end well.  Also, your code won't compile (what is `min_element`?).

Answer (score 2):

Well, first off, why are you calling find smallest number before you populate the array? It should be:

```
srand(time(NULL));

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    *(random_array + i) = rand()%1410;
    cout << random_array[i] << endl;
    cout << &*(random_array + i) << endl;
}

//move the call after you populate the array
int* smallestNumber = find_smallest_number(random_array, size);
```

Second, the code in your function should be something like:

```
int* find_smallest_number(int *random_array, int size)
{
    int* minPtr = random_array;
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if ( *(random_array + i) < *minPtr )
           minPtr = random_array + i;
    }
    return minPtr;
}
```

This way, you return a pointer to the exact element in the array. Your variant:

```
 return &min_element;
```

suggests you were returning the address of a local variable, which is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: I will try it your way....though unfortunately I have a feeling I tried it that way already. :/ Brb.

Comment: You sir, are a god amongst netizens! Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use `std::min_element` as:

```
#include <algorithm> //must include this

int* minValue = std::min_element(array, array+size);
```

Also, make sure you fill the array first, then use `std::min_element` as shown above.

It seems you need really really good C++ introductory book. Get an introductory book from this list.

- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: TBH, I have no idea how min_element works or how it's supposed to be initialized. I just grabbed it off the internet in my desperate throes of headdesk.

Comment: @ImmaD0rk: `min_element` is a function, it is not supposed to be initialized.

Comment: Since this is a school exercise, I doubt using anything from `std` would help him.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to find the smallest number in the array before you fill it with random values.  You need to initialize the array *first*, then find the smallest value.

Comment: -___- this is why I should have done this way earlier(i love this website). Moar headdesk for me, let me try to switch it up.

Comment: Grrr, nope! I am still getting that _really annoying_ error "invalid conversion from int to int*"